# Angularjs : How to switch between different implementations of a provider using DI

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

First I'd like to say my appreciation for this great website that I rely on rather often but never have used to ask anything.

I'm currently learning AngularJS by reading "Mastering web application development with AngularJS" and going through the provided examples.

I would like to understand how I can switch between different implementations of a provider (service) with minimal code change.

Here is the "notifications" service that I need to configure with different implementations of an "archiver" service, code for both below :

```
  angular.module('notificationsApp', ['archiver'])
      .provider('notificationsService', function () {
        var notifications = [];
        return {
          $get : function(archiverService) {
            return {
              push:function (notification) {
                var notificationToArchive;
                var newLen = notifications.unshift(notification);
                if (newLen > 5) {
                  notificationToArchive = notifications.pop();
                  archiverService.archive(notificationToArchive);
                }
              }
            };
          }
        };
      })

      .config(function(notificationsServiceProvider){
        **How could I make the 'archiverService' be of superConsoleArchiverService or consoleArchiverService ?**
      });
```

I would like to be able to choose between different implementations for my "archiverService", namely "superConsoleArchiverService" or "consoleArchiverService" as defined in the following module.

```
angular.module('archiver', [])
  .provider('consoleArchiverService', function () {
    return {
      $get : function() {
        return {
          archive:function (archivedNotification) {
            console.log(archivedNotification);
          }
        };
      }
    };
  })
  .provider('superConsoleArchiverService', function () {
    return {
      $get : function() {
        return {
          archive:function (archivedNotification) {
            console.log('super ' + archivedNotification);
          }
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

Thanks a lot for helping me through this !
(also, I hope this question makes sense and has not been answered a gazillion times)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have some condition, say a variable to `use_super`.

Then you could do something like this, by injecting `$provide`, and both of your providers:

```
$provide.value('archiver', use_super ? superConsoleArchiverService : consoleArchiverService);
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I finally managed to get it working ! Although I don't understand all what's going on, I hope my future studies of AngularJS will enlighten me. :)

Comment: It's basically this: you tell `$provide` that in the future, when you inject 'archiver' it should refer to the object you specify. Glad it works, mark as answer if it helped you please.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer provided by hassassin I was able to make it work, following is some working version, no code was changed in the 'archiver' module.

```
angular.module('notificationsApp', ['archiver'])
  .provider('notificationsService', function () {
    var notifications = [];
    return {
      $get : function(configuredArchiver) {
        return {
          push:function (notification) {
            var notificationToArchive;
            var newLen = notifications.unshift(notification);
            if (newLen > 5) {
              notificationToArchive = notifications.pop();
              configuredArchiver.archive(notificationToArchive);
            }
          }
        };
      }
    };
  })  
  .config(function(notificationsServiceProvider, superConsoleArchiverServiceProvider, consoleArchiverServiceProvider, $provide){
    // Here it is possible to set the 'configuredArchiver to either one of my archivers
    //$provide.provider('configuredArchiver',consoleArchiverServiceProvider);
    $provide.provider('configuredArchiver',superConsoleArchiverServiceProvider);
  });
```

Some things I still don't fully understand like why can't I inject the 'configuredArchiver' directly in the 'notificationService' provider, but I strongly suspect it is related to my still very small grasp on the life cycle of AngularJS objects. Back to reading !